# How do you add Atlassian Bamboo variable in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, bamboo

I'm having hard times to figure this out, I have the following powershell script , simple one:

```
$BambooPath = 'C:\StartFolder\*'
$RemoteWebPath = 'C:\DestFolder'
Copy-Item -Path $BambooPath -Destination $RemoteWebPath -Recurse
```

I wan't to replace in $BambooPath the C:\StartFolder* with the 
${bamboo.build.working.directory}* variable...anyone has an idea how to do that?

Comment: is it an environment variable? in that case $env:bamboo.build.working.directory

Comment: It's a Bamboo Variable only

Comment: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/37848637/how-to-reference-bamboo-plan-variables-in-powershell-script 
$bamboo_build_working_directory?

also take a look at this: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/256108/in-bamboo-how-can-you-accessedit-plan-and-global-variables-in-windows-powershell-script

Comment: Well, it doesn't seem to work for me...:( if I do the $ENV:<Bamboo Variable> it will copy the entire C: Drive:(

Comment: well, sorry i'm out of ideas ;) i suggest you write on bamboo forum

Answer (score 5):

Use underscores instead of dots to access the Bamboo environment variables:

```
$BambooPath = $Env:bamboo_build_working_directory
$RemoteWebPath = 'C:\DestFolder'
Copy-Item -Path $BambooPath -Destination $RemoteWebPath -Recurse
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have inline PS script, you can specify argument (there Argument field):

```
-BambooPath ${bamboo.build.working.directory}
```

and add your script should look like

```
param (
    [string]$BambooPath = ""
)

$RemoteWebPath = 'C:\DestFolder'
Copy-Item -Path $BambooPath -Destination $RemoteWebPath -Recurse
```